# How to Find and Recursively Read Files Using Powershell?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, powershell, find

I'm new to PowerShell and trying to recursively find XML files in a directory and read (or `cat` in unix) each file.

If this were a linux machine, I'd do something like:

```
$ find /path/to/dir/ -type f -iname *.xml -exec cat {} \;
```

I've been trying PowerShell's `Get-Content` and `Get-ChildItem` but I'm not having much luck:

```
powershell Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\ -Include *.xml -Recurse | ForEach-Object {Write-Output $_; Get-Content $_}
```

Could someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong or offer a simpler solution for finding and recursively reading files in a directory?

Comment: The command looks ok to me. What error are you getting? Does it work when you execute the command in the Powershell ISE? Following at least works on my system `gci C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\ -i *.xml -r | % { gc $_} `

Comment: i get the error "Get-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string." when using your command and modified version of my own. i dont get why its saying the path is an empty string. what do you think?

Comment: I would try using another folder and enclose it in parentheses. Does following return anything `gci "C:\" -i *.xml -r`

Comment: Yup! quotes did the trick. weird. thanks so much for your help. would you have a minute to look at my other superuser question? https://superuser.com/questions/1295125/using-powershell-with-post-requests

Comment: Your question can be improved by adding *what the curl command is supposed to do*. The -F is to specify HTTP multipart POST data apparently. I have no idea what that means.

Comment: @Lieven, sorry about that. I updated the question a bit, hopefully that helps. How would you POST the data produced from this gci command? I'm trying to do something like: `gci C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\ -i *.xml -r | % { gc $_} | Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://website.com' -Method POST -InFile $_`

Comment: not my cup of tea, sorry. I would probably send you down a wrong path if anything.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably found the answer by now but I use the following.

$files = Get-Childitem -Recurse .*.xml

Returns a list of recursively discovered xml files under the working directory

ForEach ($file in $files) {cp $file .\CommonDir}

Does some operation on each returned file (here it copies them to a common directory).

I hope this helps someone.